# While learning SharePoint 2010, what View Engine should i use in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sharepoint-2010, viewengine

While learning SharePoint 2010, what View Engine should i use in ASP.NET MVC 3?

My goal is to choose a View Engine that also helps improving my skills developing for SharePoint 2010.

My guess is the ASPX, but im not really sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no Razor in SharePoint 2010, you should probably go the ASPX way.

But Razor is really nice in ASP.NET MVC... I would probably work with both. You will spend much more time by writing XML configuration than ASPX pages in SharePoint anyway, so it's not that big deal.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, I will stick to the ASPX way as in MVC2 2. Or maybe try using them both as [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/wildturtle/archive/2010/10/13/combining-asp.net-razor-and-aspx-view-engines-in-one-project.aspx) guy.

Comment: It's of course also an option, but I don't see any advantages in using both at once. But learning both view engines won't be hard. It's quite easy stuff and similar to PHP, so I believe you won't have any problems with it. Sharepoint itself is much bigger chalenge :) Good luck anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use a modified version of Razor Views:
http://tqcblog.com/2011/01/23/asp-net-mvc-controller-actions-in-sharepoint/